# Adding leading zero to day and month that are nonzero using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date

My javascript:

```
date = '1390-1-1';
date = date.replace(/-\d{1}/g, "0$&");

// returns 13900-10-1
```

However I want this to return `1390-01-01`

How can I change the regex in order to fix the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/-([1-9])(?!\d)/g, '-0$1');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rC5eLZ/1)

- `-([1-9])`: Match hyphen followed by a digit `1-9` and capture digit in group #1
- `(?!\d)`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have a digit ahead
- Replacement is `-0$1` that puts `0` before single digit